# Soundcloud API: Querying for users by country

Tags: python, soundcloud

I am using the python wrapper and trying to find users from a specific country.
I believe the following line of code should return users from Poland, but instead I get many users with other countries or "none" as a country. I check the user country by doing a print user.country

```
users = client.get('/users', country='Poland');
```

Here are the resources I have been using:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#search
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

If anyone can help me out here I would appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Country is not a field that can be filtered. For users only q='' is supported. For the time being it seems the only way to get this data is through a manual search http://soundcloud.com/people/search?q%5Bcountry_code%5D= where the country_code is the 2 letter identifier for a country.